# How to reset all changes in the previous commit and merge it with actual?

Tags: git

I have 3 commit: 
master -> v1 -> v2
Inside v1 we found problems and decided to discard all changes in it.
How I can reset this changes in v2 ?

I tried switch to branch v1 and run "git reset --hard HEAD^". What the next step? I tried now checkout to v2 and merge it with v1, but it does`t work.

Comment: Did you mean *current*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you would want to use `git revert` here:

```
# from your branch
git log
```

Find the SHA-1 hash of the `v1` commit and record it somewhere.  Then revert:

```
git revert abc123
```

This will add a new commit on top of your branch which functionally undoes whatever changes the `v1` commit introduced.

Note that a hard reset won't work here, not without also nuking the `v2` commit, because all it can do it move the `HEAD` and all other pointers back some number of commits.  If you wanted to go the route of rewriting your history to remove `v1`, then an interactive rebase *could* do that.  But in general rewriting the history of a Git branch is not desirable, assuming that branch be already public and possibly in use by other users.